# How to change akka Actors logLevel at runtime with application.conf

Tags: logging, akka, logback, slf4j, application.conf

How can I set application.conf to be able to change akka logLevel at runtime? Are there any properties I can set?
I'm using slf4j and logback as backend. I've just set my logback.xml:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
    .....
</configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable DEBUG in your `application.conf` and rely entirely on logback to filter statements out based on log level.

Make sure to  enable the `Slf4jLoggingFilter` in your config to not get a performance hit when DEBUG in logback is not enabled:

```
logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
```